# What is the process that you follow to create model in Django?

Tags: django

What is the process that you follow to create model in Django? Thanks.

Comment: "concrete question"? This too broad and too vague to answer.

Comment: @dirkgroten Edited.

Comment: What was unclear in the documentation?

Comment: The edit has made this even more vague and impossible to answer.

Comment: I have the end product that I want in mind but I don't know what technical details my project requires. How would I choose the technical methods and attributes (etc.) from the documentation if I have never implemented everything from the documentation? Starting a project from tutorials is a piece of cake but build one's own app with the help of documentation is much less easy. Ex: how would I know that I can't search a foreign key in django admin even before getting an error. Is there a proper way to plan a(n) (Django) app models.py?

Comment: What you are asking is the absolute basic. You have to do this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ and this https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/ I understand what you asking but it's the basics

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is django specific or a more general programming question: how to model your software architecture. You can't *not* make mistakes, that's why you should cut your problem into small pieces, build them bit by bit and refactor as need arises. There are loads of books written on the topic, that's why this question doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: @lakovos Belonias I'm trying to see how different my approach is from your message. I know those tutorials already, so I'm ok with the technicalities. Do you fix issues on a case by case basis all the time or do you plan your models to avoid further issues? Does your model.py have to be simple all the time or can it be complex? What is your approach?

Comment: @dirkgroten My questions touches a bit of both areas actually. Not Python specific, not Django specific. I guess not all Python developers use Django all the time.

Comment: Models have fields and methods. The fields come from the business requirements of your application: what data needs to be saved and what does the data represent? The methods are the public API of your models. Anything that has to do with business logic should stay in the model (the "M" in MVC). As your application grows (and business requirements change) it's unavoidable that you'll have to make changes to your models, split models, add new relationships, etc... You can't design the perfect app from the start.

Comment: Thanks dirkgroten. Great explanation. Modeling a database is a absolute must. It must also well be planned (I guess). Is there a resource you follow in this respect (for Django) that is not a tutorial (only) but on the approach itself like your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

> The most important part of a model – and the only required part of a model – is the list of database fields it defines. Fields are specified by class attributes. Be careful not to choose field names that conflict with the models API like clean, save, or delete.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

You can start here [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#fields)

See also [Django Girls Models](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_models/#django-models)

Comment: If you added a class like "Order", in your "django admin", you would like to know who purchased an album by customer mentioning the name of musician of the album. How would you do it? With a ForeignKey? And in your django admin backend, how would you search for an album ordered? What part of documentation can you look up to achieve this goal? I'm talking about your approach.